# Disable WSDL Cache in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, caching, wsdl

I am using SoapExtensionReflector to modify the WSDL sent to the client due to a complex proxy setup.  This modification is based on a query string variable:

whatever.com/Service.asmx?WSDL&customaddress=proxy.whatever.com

This works well, and the modification is successful.  However, the WSDL is cached by ASP.NET the first time, so a second call to, say...

whatever.com/Service.asmx?WSDL&customaddress=dohicky.whatever.com

will still use the variables from the original call.  I would like to disable WSDL caching and force ASP.NET to reprocess the WSDL every time.  Is there an easy way to do this programmatically?

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Comment: It is possible to add a kind of timestamp on uri? Like whatever.com/Service.asmx?WSDL&customaddress=dohicky.whatever.com&ts=20150810211303? This will force a new request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180513/disable-asp-net-cache