# ASP.NET page keeps caching

Tags: asp.net, caching

Is there a way to stop a page from caching in .NET?

I don't see anything in this application that explicitly tries to cache anything from the site but it still does cache it and the only way to clear it is by restarting the application..

the problem is not browser cache btw

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please be more precise in your question. How do you know that the problem is not a browser cache? Maybe requests to the server are cached? If yes it's good to use jquery function: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to disable caching for one page (read: .aspx) place the following code in the `Page_Init()`

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Alternativly you can set in .aspx file: `<%@ OutputCache Location="None" %>`

Additional information:

- [Disable ASP.net Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180513/disable-asp-net-cache)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9s3a17d.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1ysf1y.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z852zf6b.aspx